# Graceful termination of a Java program and logging of terminate signals

Tags: java, multithreading, runtime, signals

In a Java 8 application running on Linux (CentOS 6), I want to be able to gracefully terminate it and log the type of caught signals (SIGTERM, SIGINT, SIGHUP).

```
    private static volatile boolean die = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
    {

            // Catch terminate signals
            Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(
                    new Thread()
                    {
                            @Override
                            public void run()
                            {
                                    System.out.println("Caught signal " + ???);
                                    die = true;
                                    System.exit(1);
                            }
                    }
            );


            int i = 0;
            while (true && !die) {
                    System.out.println("Test " + i++);
                    Thread.sleep(4000);
            }

            if (die) {
                    System.out.println("Dying...");
                    Runtime.getRuntime().halt(1);
            }
 }
```

1. Is this a good way to implement graceful termination?
2. How can I print out the caught signal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this a good way to implement graceful termination?

You aren't doing much, so *graceful* doesn't really mean anything. Shutdown hooks really are the only way to handle these signals.

> How can I print out the caught signal?

You can't. The signal is caught at the JVM level. It'll run `System#exit(int)` (or rather `Shutdown#exit(int)`). The JVM does not provide any extra information you can use.

Answer (score 0):

Check sun.misc.SignalHandler  (  http://www.docjar.com/html/api/sun/misc/SignalHandler.java.html ).

Other way would be to use JNI interface to install the signal handlers where the native handlers will invoke some Java code to do the real stuff.